# How to open filter view without opening a new tab or browser window using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to open filter views via button. If I understood it correctly, this should be possible by now. But I'm not sure, because I don't understand the whole communication on the following topic:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753410)

I have written the following code. When I execute this code, I always get the error: "Method getFilter(object) not found". What

What am I doing wrong?

```
function OpenFilter(){


      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Name of the sheet'); //The sheet in which I want to open the filter view
      var rg = sheet.getRange("S1:S2"); //There is the range where my Hyperlink is placed
      var link = rg.getCell(1,1).getValues(); // The cell of the Hyperlink to test
      var filter = sheet.getFilter(link);

SpreadsheetApp.setFilter(filter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the method `setFilter(filter)` has not been implemented so far.

Also, the method `getFilter()` does not accept parameters, see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfilter).

I recommend you to have a look [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters) to find examples what you can do with filters at current stage.

Keep in mind that you need to combine `SpreadsheetApp` with the [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) to achieve your goal.